# Processing large number of records from a file in Java

Tags: java

I have million records in CSV file which has 3 columns id,firstName,lastName. I have to process this file in java and validate that id should be unique, firstName should not be null. If there are scenarios where id is not unique and/or firstName is null then I have to write these records in an output file with a fourth column as the reason("id not unique"/"firstName is NULL"). Performance should be good. Please suggest the best effective way.

Comment: What things have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection (ArrayList) to store all the ID's in it in a loop and check if it doesn't already exist. If it doest, write it in a file.

The code should be like this:

```
if(!idList.contains(id)){
    idList.add(id);
}else{
    writer.write(id);
}
```

The above code should work in a loop for all the records being read from the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks Safeer.This is helpful. but i am looking for something where system memory is not able to handle million records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCsv jar for the purpose you have specified. It's under Apache 2.0 licence.
You can download the jar from 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencsv22jar.htm

below is the code for the same

Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(INPUT_SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);

```
    Writer writer = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(OUTPUT_SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer);

    List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
    for (String[] row : list) {
        //assuming First column to be Id
        String id = row[0];
        //assuming name to be second column
        String name = row[1];
        //assuming lastName to be third column
        String lastName = row[2];

        //Put your pattern here
        if(id==null || !id.matches("pattern") || name==null || !name.matches("pattern")){
            String[] outPutData = new String[]{id, name , lastName, "Invalid Entry"};
            csvWriter.writeNext(outPutData);
        }
    }
```

let me know if this works or you need further help or clarifications.

Comment: this is quite good. but i am looking for something where system memory is not able to handle million records.

Comment: @bhaskar narula what does it even means ? please provide more clarifications and update your query with file size or number of records or with other issue specifically u r facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good performance algorithm, you should not use `ArrayList.contains(element)` as explained here, uses O(n) complexity. Instead I suggest you to use a `HashSet` as the `HashSet.Contains(element)` operation has an O(1) complexity. To make things short, with ArrayList you would make 1,000,000^2 operations, while with HashSet you would use 1,000,000 operations.

In pseudo-code (to not give away the full answer and make you find the answer on your own) I would do this:

```
File outputFile
String[] columns
HashSet<String> ids
for(line in file):
    columns = line.split(',')
    if(ids.contains(columns.id):
        outputFile.append(columns.id + " is not unique")
        continue
    if(columns.name == null):
        outputFile.append("first name is null!")
        continue
    ids.add(columns.id)
```

Comment: this is quite good. but i am looking for something where system memory is not able to handle million records.

Comment: Then I recommend that you store the unique ids in a sorted temp file and whenever you want another record you binary search it with a log(n) complexity.In this case you do not use ram, only disk space.